# Configuring smartdocs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700842/google-cloud-endpoints-esp-grpc-transcoding-to-camel-case), is there a way to configure a Google Cloud Endpoints gRPC service (using ESP) such that the auto-generated SmartDocs for REST (and gRPC) don't use camel case, but instead preserve the snake case of the .proto files?

I've already figured out how to run ESP such that ESP itself preserves the case in the transcoding: by passing --transcoding_preserve_proto_field_names to the executable when it runs.

But now my auto-generated REST documentation doesn't match the actual API!

Help!

Comment: @wayne-zhang Any help from the google cloud endpoints people?

Comment: @ivan-li Same as ^^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a limitation with Cloud Endpoints Portal. The Portal does not have access to the --transcoding_preserve_proto_field and assumes that the field names are being camel cased.